# How to use transactions in a controller in Scala

Tags: database, scala, architecture, transactions, slick

I am trying to write into multiple tables in my controller. And i want all those rows to be transactional in nature. I can put them in slick withTransaction block, but this is business logic and I don't want to put it in database layer. Also, if one table is moved to another database, then I wont be able to put them in slick transaction. Is there anything like distributed transactions or like Akka STM available?

Here is the code I am using

```
class PatientController {
    def create(patient: Patient, allergy : Allergy){
        PatientRepository.add(patient);
        PatientRepository.addAllergy(allergy)
    }
    def createWithTransaction(patient: Patient, allergy : Allergy){
        transactionBlock{
           PatientRepository.add(patient);
           PatientRepository.addAllergy(allergy)
           mq.put(1)
        }
    }    
}

class PatientRepository {

    def add(patient: Patient) = {
        database.withSession {
            Patients.insert(patient)
        }
    }
    def addCase(allergy: Allergy) = {
        database.withSession {
            Allergies.insert(allergy)        
        }
    }

    def addPatientWithAllergy(patient:Patient, allergy: Allergy){
        database withTransaction {
            Patients.insert(patient)
            Allergies.insert(allergy)    
        }
    }

    object Patients extends Table[Patient]("patients"){
        def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
        def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
        def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
    }   
    object PatientAllergies extends Table[Allergy]("patient_allergies"){
        def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
        def allergyName = column[String]("allergy_name")
        def severity = column[Int]("severity")
        def patientId = column[UUID]("patient_id")
        def allergyFK = foreignKey("patient_allergies_fk", patientId, Patients)(_.id)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do better with Slick right now. We will be adding composeable transactions at some point (aka transaction monad) which may give more flexibility. And isn't the fact that something needs to be executed as a transaction logically part of your data model, not your business logic?

Comment: Can you give a timeline on when you think this will happen?  This is actually a big deal for me.

Also, are you going to build more controls over transactions (isolation for example)?

Comment: no timeline for monadic transactions. Regarding isolation level, you can access the underlying jdbc connection and set the isolation level. See this example: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/218